# run multiple scripts

Tags: perl, bash

I have a number of bash scripts. for example

```
script1_1.sh
script1_2.sh
script1_3.sh
```

etc....

I was wondering, is there a way for me to run these all in another script. where by I don't have to manually add each. So through the use of a for loop? where it increments a number like

```
for (i=0; i < 40; i++)
   ./script1_[i].sh
```

I would also like to check each script worked, so if not, it would exit the for loop.

```
if ./script[i] (command unsuccessful)
then break?
```

Can anyone help me write this code? i'm very new to scripting languages.

Comment: Have you googled for bash docs? We're happy to help fix something that's not working. We're not here to write something from scratch.

Comment: well I have, im just not sure how to check each script worked or not, and to break from loop if so

Comment: google's your friend: "bash exit status" -> http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html

Comment: @MarcB That guide is terrible, especially for a new scripter. The saying in #bash on irc.freenode.net is that it "teaches people to write bugs, not scripts". http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are really close to answering your own question. The C-style for loop will work fine for your scenario, but if your scripts are randomly named, you can use an array. You can use `||`, which will execute the right side if a non-zero exit status is returned. You could also use an if statement like you have proved in your question, with a "!" between if in the command (if not).

```
scripts=( script1_1.sh script1_2.sh script1_3.sh )

for script in "${scripts[@]}"; do
   ./"$script" || { echo "$script failed"; break; }
done
```

Using the for loop like in your questions:

```
for ((i=1;i<4;i++)); do
   ./script1_${i}.sh || { echo "$script failed"; break; }
done
```

Comment: I just tried that out and its perfect! Thank you so much for the help, its exactly what I was aiming to do

Answer (score 0):

Since you have this question tagged with `perl`, you can also do this in a Perl one-liner:

```
perl -e 'foreach(1..40){system("sh script_" . $_ . ".sh")==0 or die $!;print "script_" . $_ . ".sh done\n";}'
```

Comment: You probably meant to `warn` and not `die`

Comment: @Zaid - Well, the OP mentioned that he/she "would also like to check each script worked, so if not, [then] exit the for loop," hence why I had it `die` upon failure.  You do bring up a good point, though, in that it's not always necessary to `die`.